# how can I get the attribute2 value when attribute1, python, xml

Tags: python, xml

```
<book>
<propery name= "Hello world", value ="0"/>
<propery name ="I'm new", value ="1"/>

</book>
```

Like I want to search the propery when name'Hello world", then print/modify the value of this element

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML parser from Python Standard Library (`xml.etree.elementTree`):

```
s='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
<propery name="Hello world" value="0"/>
<propery name="Im new" value 
="1"/>
</book>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
myroot = ET.fromstring(s)

for item in myroot:
    if item.attrib["name"] == "Hello world":
        print(item.attrib["value"])
```

- First you load the XML into `s` as string.
- Then load its root element into `myroot` through `ET.fromString()`
- Loop over the children of root element `book`
- And find which element has name "Hello World"
- And output Value attribute

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using an xml parser, your life will be easier. I personally use xmltodict, but there are others.

If you just want to do a one off quick extraction you may use regex, something like:

`value = re.search('"Hello world".*?value[^"]*"([^"]*)"', xmltext)`

The above one will get you the "value" you are looking for. I personally prefer to wrap regex something like the below, so it's less hassle:

`value = (re.findall('"Hello world".*?value[^"]*"([^"]*)"', xmltext) or [None])[0]`

Still, a parser is recommended if you want to extract many, or modify the value and get xml back.

Comment: Thank you :) as the newbie, the above sentence is hard for me. But thank you anyway!